# Gzip and rename (remove .gz extension) all files except images and PDFs?

Tags: compression, gzip

I am able to gzip every file in a directory (`mydirectory`) using the command:

```
gzip --suffix .gz --recursive mydirectory
```

But...

1. I don't want the images (.ico, .jpg, .png, .gif) and PDFs (.pdf) files within the directory to be gzipped.
2. And those files that are gzipped have the `.gz` extension. I don't want that. For example, I'd like the gzipped `index.html` file be `index.html` itself, and NOT `index.html.gz`.

So, how do I do this, optimally/efficiently?

---

**Here's how I am doing this now (a pretty lengthy process).**

Compress all files in `mydirectory` but don't delete/replace original files:

```
cd ~/mydirectory

find . -type f | \
while read -r x
do
  gzip -c -9 "$x" > "$x.gz"
done
```

Remove all gzipped image and PDF files:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.ico.gz" -exec rm -f {} \;
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg.gz" -exec rm -f {} \;
find . -type f -iname "*.png.gz" -exec rm -f {} \;
find . -type f -iname "*.gif.gz" -exec rm -f {} \;
find . -type f -iname "*.pdf.gz" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Rename the existing gzipped files, essentially removing the `.gz` extension from their name:

```
cd

for f in `find mydirectory -iname '*.gz'`; do
  mv $f ${f%.gz} 
done
```

What we pretty much have now are gzipped text files (.html, .xml, .css, .js) without .gz extension, and uncompressed/un-gzipped images and PDFs.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: make a backup. Then use `find` to filter your files and run gzip and then move the file back to the original filename:

```
find -type f -not \( -iname '*.ico' -or -iname '*.jpg' -or -iname '*.png' -or -iname '*.gif' \) -exec gzip "{}" \; -exec mv "{}.gz" "{}" \;
```

This is a destructive command so please be careful. Remove the `-exec...` commands to begin with to make sure it's only selecting files you want to compress.

Comment: Great, but half the answer. Now all I need is that they don't have the `.gz` extension (which they do, as of now).

Comment: @TheoneManis Yeah sorry was struggling with getting the exec to work. Turns out you can add more than one so that fixes everything.

Comment: Problem! Just checked my site on REDbot, and I saw this error: _"This response was compressed using GZip, but the data was corrupt."_ Is something wrong with the command? (see for yourself: http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Faahank.com%2F)

Comment: Something's really wrong with the command, the way I see it. Other ways I've tried output proper gzipped files.